# How to make this curl request in NodeJS request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, request

```
curl -H "Authentication: <security token>" "https://a.bcsc.com/app/api/v2/<api-key>/<query type>?<optional parameters>"

request({
                url: <<endpoint>>,
                headers: {
                    Authentication: mpulseAuthToken
                }
            },function (error, response, body) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                } else {
                    console.log(body);
                }
            });
```

How can I make the above `curl` request in Node JS using the request module. I already have the security token handy with me.

Comment: This looks straightforward... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @smarx Here is my code. Wondering what is wrong. `request({
                    url: data.mpulse.apiEndPoint+data.mpulse.apiKey.toUpperCase()+"/timer-metrics?date=Last3Hours&timer=PageLoad&timezone=US/Eastern",
                    headers: {
                        Authentication: mpulseAuthToken
                    }
                },function (error, response, body) {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                }); `

Comment: Please put the code in the question. It's nearly unreadable as a comment.

Comment: "Wondering what is wrong." We're wondering that too. What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple:

```
const request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'https://a.bcsc.com/app/api/v2/',
    headers: {
       Authentication: '<security token>'
    }
},
function(error, response, body) 

  console.log(response);

});
```

Check the documentation on [Github](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers)

Comment: this is my code..   request({
                    url: <<endpoint>>,
                    headers: {
                        Authentication: AuthToken
                    }
                },function (error, response, body) {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    } else {
                        console.log(body);
                    }
                });

Comment: @SarnathJegadeesan, so what is the issue. Did you debug?

Comment: I get a `HTTP 404 on program` and `HTTP 401 UnAuthorized` on POSTMAN

Comment: Those two errors are not something I (or anyone) here could you help with. Please, refer to the API documents (if any) for details on how to connect to their service.

Comment: But my problem is it works on shell with a simple curl! I would rather read API docs, had it been a bookish problem :)

Comment: If the `curl` command works and your code doesn't, there must be some difference between the two. All you have is a URL and one header. It should be easy enough to print both out and spot the difference. No one but you can do that, of course, since you're the only one who has that information.

Answer (score 0):

@sarnath-jegadeesan, Depending on the context of where the request is made to the mPulse API endpoints, it may be blocked.  This happens typically when the request is made from within a browser.  A simple workaround for this scenario is to proxy the requests.  I've done this using a property configuration on Akamai CDN and it works well.

You can find decent documentation here on how to make requests to the Akamai mPulse query API: https://developer.akamai.com/api/web_performance/mpulse_query/v2.html